# how can retrieve a checked list of objects from ObjectListView c#?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm using [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) with checkboxes, I would like to run a function on selected items to delete them. So i tried this Method but it not working:

```
private List<Matricule> matrs;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //List<Song> s = this.olvSongs.CheckedObjects.Count;
            //MessageBox.Show(this.olvSongs.CheckedItems.Count + "  " + this.olvSongs.CheckedObjects.Count);

            string s = "";
            foreach (var item in olvMatrs.SelectedItems)
            {
                matrs.Remove((Matricule)item);
            }
this.olvSongs.SetObjects(matrs);
        }
```

how can i do this task.

Comment: "but it not working" is not helpful. Error message? Expected vs actual result? ...etc.

Comment: no error message, just nothing happened when i click the button :(

Comment: Rev gave a good answer. You should mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You talk about check boxes. The line

```
foreach (var item in olvMatrs.SelectedItems)
```

iterates through the ITEMS that are SELECTED, not CHECKED! Is that really what you want?
To get the CHECKED OBJECTS use

```
objectListView1.CheckedObjects
```

If you really want to get the SELECTED OBJECTS, don't use Selected*Items*. Use

```
objectListView1.SelectedObjects;
```

instead. Thats what the OLV is all about. You want to work with the objects, not with ListViewItems.

If you decided WHAT you want to remove, don't remove the objects from your List, but directly from your ObjectListView using

```
objectListView1.RemoveObjects(myObjects);
```

You should probably (re-)read [this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html). Especially the section "Mental gear shift - This is important. You need to understand this.".

Answer (score 1):

well, i see that you don't show the code where it adds anything to matrs, so we are certainly short of useful source code. Also, we don't know what a Matricule is, but i can take a pretty good guess with what you already shared.

i believe 1 of 3 things must be happening if matrs is not getting any items removed.

1: are you sure your function is tied to the click event of the button? you can set a break point in the function to make sure it is even executing. or you can add a line to show a messagebox `MessageBox.Show("Yes", this.Text);` inside that button1_Click() method.

2: if the function is being executed (so it is not option #1), then my 2nd consideration is that perhaps the `(Matricule)item` is not in the matrs List to be able to be deleted. that Remove function returns a boolean value indicating whether the remove actually deleted something or not.

3: are you sure it is not getting deleted and that what is really happening is that it really is being deleted but your new updated List is not being shown to you?

I believe you think it is #2, but might want to eliminated the possibility of the other 2 easier options (#1 and #3) first. if you do deduce it to be #2, so options #1 and #3 are not happening, then here's the thing with deleting objects by referencing those objects: it easily leads to problems like what you are having. it is so easy to have code that actually attempts to delete a new object with the same properties as another object that is in a `List`. the clean way that i solve this is try to remove items by their index # rather than a reference to the object itself. but you are not even grabbing the object to be deleted from the List itself. you are grabbing that object from olvMatrs, which is another object list. my best guess from the information you shared is that this is why it's not working, that if you look deeper, that you are trying to Remove an object that is not in the list, so nothing is being Removed. it's an easy mistake to make. i only know because i've done it too before i learned to be super careful about this.

Comment: if this was helpful to you, please vote up. (i hope to build my reputation since i don't have much yet.)

Comment: thanks @Shawn for your reply, i used olvMatrs.CheckedObjects and it works

Comment: thanks, so it was trying to remove the wrong object then (my #2 above), and Rev1.0 explains the problem more clearly then. thanks for the feedback, Sidaoui. and thanks for the better clarity, Rev!